# How to input words in sentences into unique list

Tags: java

Hello guys maybe you maybe can help . here is my problem

For example : "I am running all over the time every time with my dog and my sister"

I want to have a list containing all the unique words from the above sentences :

List data = {I,am,running,all,over,the,time,every,with,my,dog,and,sister}

I already tried this code below but it runs slow with big sentences

```
List textList = new ArrayList();
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text);

    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        String tokenData = (String) stringTokenizer.nextElement();
        if ((textList.size() > 0)) {
            Boolean exist = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < textList.size(); i++) {
                if (tokenData.toLowerCase().equals(
                        textList.get(i).toString().toLowerCase()))
                    exist = true;
            }
            if (exist == false)
                textList.add(tokenData);
        } else {
            textList.add(tokenData);
        }

    }
```

Is there anyway other than this faster way but same result . I appreciate your reply thx

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "big sentence" that you've tried?  How long did it take when you ran it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
String data = "I am running all over the time every time with my dog and my sister";
String[] arr = data.split(" ");

Set<String> st = new HashSet<String>();

st.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Set only allows unique values and will ignore duplicates.

Comment: Maybe you should do you a `toLowerCase` before the split. Since the OP (@Carlo) seems to need a Case Insensitive Set. Or Use `TreeSet(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` instead of a HashSet

Answer (score 4):

try this:

1. Create an array by splitting your string by space.
2. Create a list from that array.
3. Create a Set from that list to remove duplicates.

<del>`Set data = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(yourString.split(" ")));`</del>

`Set<String> data = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(yourString.split(" ")));`

Again create a list from this set which will be the result.

Comment: +1 for more detailed answer, I would recommend using generics though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Set<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which does not contain duplicates.

If you want to convert it to list, it is as simple as:

```
List<String> listVersion = new ArrayList<String>(mySet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set instead. That way you can just add the word each time without checking for duplicates, as sets don't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Split the sentence with space("") as delimiter and store them in a Set (Collection) .
Use **split()** function.
As Set can store only unique elements you will get rid of redundant words.

```
String str  = "I am running all over the time every time with my dog and my sister" ;
String delim = "";
String[] splits = str.split(delim);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> uniqWords = new HashSet<String>();
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text);

while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    String tokenData = (String) stringTokenizer.nextElement();
    uniqWords.add(tokenData.toLowerCase());
}

// Now you can retreive the words as array
// uniqWords.toarray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your code is at least O(n*n) in the worst case. In addition to the standard Java Set version solution, you may also try to 1) create an array by splitting the string by space, 2) sort the array, 3) remove the duplicated elements.